# Talend Open Studio adding missing modules

Tags: talend

I just installend Talend Open Studio for Big Data version 6.4.1, and I created a job with tHiveConnection component. It has some missing modules that I have to install. Is anybody have a link with description of what is the best way to do it? Should I install them one by one (there is quite a lot of them)?

Comment: you can refer this link "https://help.talend.com/reader/wDRBNUuxk629sNcI0dNYaA/2A0a68Lcj3Rmm0AH4VGqxw" , for sample use of   tHiveConnection and it's documentation.

Comment: This documentation doesn't answer my question... I am now doing it one by one, but it is very long process and Modules window is very slow which doesn't help

Comment: have u triend installing all the rquired modules at once by going Help > Install Additional Packages, showing the Optional and Required third-party libraries options

Comment: Hi, I just downloaded everything, so now problem solved. It is still not clear why Modules window is so slow, doesn't make sense.